# Prevent the button from hiding when scrolling toolbar

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am building an application and i want in an Activity to have the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. Everything works fine except the fact that when i scroll to the very top half of the button goes underneath the toolbar like this:

[image]

what i want to achieve is this:

[image]

my layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_game_info"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="210dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="-70dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageDescTropos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:contentDescription="Nothing"
                android:src="@drawable/download"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:titleEnabled="false"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/game_full_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="13.5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:text="Game Name"
                android:fadeScrollbars="true"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/my_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Category"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                android:background="@color/game_info_jackpot_background">

                <TextView
                    android:text="Text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                    android:layout_marginTop="9.5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:id="@+id/textView" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer iaculis luctus elementum. Maecenas ultricies volutpat mollis. Pellentesque lacinia euismod libero. Integer ullamcorper nulla suscipit eros maximus, at sollicitudin ante faucibus. Nulla semper purus ac dignissim porttitor. Sed in nisl posuere, fermentum arcu id, ultricies nibh. Morbi a pulvinar arcu, nec varius massa. Mauris ut sagittis magna. Etiam feugiat ut neque ac congue. Maecenas quis felis eget elit placerat venenatis ut ut nisl. Sed condimentum libero condimentum bibendum imperdiet. Sed non libero a odio faucibus consectetur. Nunc dignissim nisl ut nibh lacinia, a commodo tellus venenatis. Aenean diam diam, volutpat at aliquet id, tempor ut odio. Nunc sit amet egestas lectus, in consequat magna."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="13.5dp"
                android:id="@+id/textView2" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_Button_Play"
        android:text="@string/play_now"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appBar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

How can i achieve the button not to hide?

**UPDATE**

I have noticed that if i replace the `Button` with a `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton` it just hides by itself. So the problem is with the widget. Anyone have any idea how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: try adding elevation to the button, and move it to the top in xml, it has to be the first child of his parent

Comment: move it to the top? top of where?

Comment: it has to be the first element declared in his parent layout, so, you open CoordinatorLayout, and right after you declare your Button

Comment: it says No resource found to match the given name at layout_anchor with value of id. Which means i cannot put the button before the appbar since it cannot be anchored to it

Answer (score 0):

This should work, it said that because noone declared the ID, now Button declared the id appBar_layout, and the barLayout only uses it. I also added elevation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_game_info"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_Button_Play"
        android:text="@string/play_now"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/appBar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@id/appBar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="210dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="-70dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageDescTropos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:contentDescription="Nothing"
                android:src="@drawable/download"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:titleEnabled="false"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/game_full_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="13.5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:text="Game Name"
                android:fadeScrollbars="true"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                tools:targetApi="jelly_bean" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/my_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Category"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                android:background="@color/game_info_jackpot_background">

                <TextView
                    android:text="Text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                    android:layout_marginTop="9.5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:id="@+id/textView" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer iaculis luctus elementum. Maecenas ultricies volutpat mollis. Pellentesque lacinia euismod libero. Integer ullamcorper nulla suscipit eros maximus, at sollicitudin ante faucibus. Nulla semper purus ac dignissim porttitor. Sed in nisl posuere, fermentum arcu id, ultricies nibh. Morbi a pulvinar arcu, nec varius massa. Mauris ut sagittis magna. Etiam feugiat ut neque ac congue. Maecenas quis felis eget elit placerat venenatis ut ut nisl. Sed condimentum libero condimentum bibendum imperdiet. Sed non libero a odio faucibus consectetur. Nunc dignissim nisl ut nibh lacinia, a commodo tellus venenatis. Aenean diam diam, volutpat at aliquet id, tempor ut odio. Nunc sit amet egestas lectus, in consequat magna."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="13.5dp"
                android:id="@+id/textView2" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: well it does not work: `Error:(17, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_anchor' with value '@id/appBar_layout')`.

Comment: how can you say i want this button anchored by this id and this id comes after the button? for sure i dont think it has to be before the appbar layout. I think there is some mistake with the elevation. I do not blame you of course but it just does not even compile

Comment: Look better at my code. Button adds the ID. And the appbar just use it.

Comment: i still get the same thing. it just hides underneath

Comment: i think the problem is with the button. Try to put a `FloatingActionButton` without changing anything to see what happens...Just switch the `Button` with `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton`